# Why I append a item in one of a list in a dictionary and all others list also change?

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
def init_dic(init):
    return {str(i):init for i in range(0,5)}

a = init_dic([])
print('Origin: ', a)

a['1'].append('test')
print('After append: ', a)
```

And the result:

```
Origin:  {'3': [], '4': [], '0': [], '1': [], '2': []}
After append:  {'3': ['test'], '4': ['test'], '0': ['test'], '1': ['test'], '2': ['test']}
```

But I expect the result should be:

```
Origin:  {'3': [], '4': [], '0': [], '1': [], '2': []}
After append:  {'3': [], '4': [], '0': [], '1': ['test'], '2': []}
```

Why this happens? I have no idea how so...

So if I want the correct result, how should I do to correct my code?

Comment: Reading this, I wonder if you just want to use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` anyway. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is here:

```
def init_dic(init):
    return {str(i):init for i in range(0,5)}
```

returned dictionary will have values that are pointing to the same object in memory:

```
>>> a['1'] is a['2']
True
```

avoid this by making copies of init:

```
def init_dic(init):
    return {str(i):init[:] for i in range(0,5)}
```

Recommended reading:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/
https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types

Answer (score 1):

All your `dict` values are references to the same `list` object. Appending to it will affect all of them. This problem will always arise when your `init` param is mutable. For immutable parameters (int, float, tuple, etc), it will work.

You could do the following (in case you know `init` will be a `list`):

```
def init_dic(init):
    return {str(i): init[:] for i in range(0,5)}  # use a copy
```

A more general approach would be to provide a factory (a 0-argument callable producing the actual value) as `init` and use as follows:

```
def init_dic(init):
    return {str(i): init() for i in range(0,5)}  # factory is called for each iteration

a = init_dic(lambda: [])
# a = init_dic(list)
```

As Kojiro points out, this then resembles a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), albeit an eager one and for a limited number of keys.