# Value in dictionary changes when variable changes

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Trying to grab certain values from a json file and then 're-create' a new json file (sort of like a conversion). In the code below. I do the following:

1. define function that returns an dictionary
2. for each item in json, if function returns results, add results to list located inside parentObj dictionary

oldFile.json:

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "fieldValues": [
                {
                "id": "101",
                "value": "John"
                },
                {
                "id": "102",
                "value": "Doe"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldValues": [
                {
                "id": "101",
                "value": "Jane"
                },
                {
                "id": "102",
                "value": "Doe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

file.py

```
import json
import os

output = {}
parentObj = {}
parentObj['entries'] = []

def grabVals(iCounter):
   # legend is a pre-determined dictionary matching ids with names (like first/last) 
   for myKey in subResults['elements'][iCounter]['fieldValues']:
        if myKey['id'] in legend:
            if 'value' in  myKey:
                newEntry = {legend[myKey['id']]: myKey['value']}
                output.update(newEntry) # first adds 'John', then 'Doe'
   # sample output below; next iteration would be 'Jane Doe'
   # {"First": "John", "Last": "Doe"}
   return output

subResults = json.loads(oldFile.json)

formCount = len(subResults['elements']) # subResults is the json above file. Grab total number of entries
for counter in range(0, formCount):
    if convertTime(formEntryStamp, formEntryID) == 'keep':  # self defined function (returns keep or None)       
        parentObj['entries'].append(grabVals(counter))
    else:
        pass

export = json.dumps(parent_obj, indent=4, sort_keys=False) # create new json based of dictionary

f = open("finished.json", "w")
f.write(export)
f.close()
```

Expected data in `finished.json`

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "First": "John",
            "Last": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "First": "Jane",
            "Last": "Doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Actual data in `finished.json`:

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "First": "Jane",
            "Last": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "First": "Jane",
            "Last": "Doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question: How do I permanently write to parentObj? When `output` is changed in the function, the value inside `parentObj` is overwritten with new value. Does this have something to do mututable/immutable objects? Please let me know any further clarification is required.

Related links are similar, but refer to lists, whereas my is an object/dictionary:

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951816/python-changes-to-my-copy-variable-affect-the-original-variable)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605689/why-i-append-a-item-in-one-of-a-list-in-a-dictionary-and-all-others-list-also-ch?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Um, what do you think `grabVals(counter)` is doing, because AFAIKT it always returns `{"result of": "conditional statement"}` and it never uses the argument passed to it... and what is with the `else: pass` which also seems to do nothing...

Comment: In other words, please provide a sample input, the output you are getting, and the output you are *expecting*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your given code into a text file and reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think we're stemming away from the true question. The problem is that once I add data to `parentObj` using a variable (i.e. `parentObj['entries'].append(myVar)` ), and then later `myVar` is reused and equals something else, whatever was previously written in `parentObj` gets changed to new value. Once again very similiar to linked question. @juanpa.arrivillaga @Prune

Comment: @Kervvv right, but we cannot reproduce your error, and you have a function that is only acting as a placeholder, and the root of the behavior you are seeing *likely stems from the particulars of that function*, so there is no way to know. But in any event, likely you are reusing the same dictionary, and simply *mutating it*, then appending that same dictionary to your list.

Comment: I added the instructions the function performs to my code, thank you for the instruction. I will look further into how to mutate a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some reading on mutation of objects in python (link [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/mutation.html)), the code below solved my problem. Similar to what Juanpa said in the comments, I *mutated* the variable that was being re-used in my function (`output`). I assume with the code below, I am creating a copy thus leaving the original untouched.

```
def grabVals(iCounter, output=None):
    if output == None:
        output = {}
        for myKey in subResults['elements'][iCounter]['fieldValues']:
            if myKey['id'] in legend:
                if 'value' in  myKey:
                    newEntry = {legend[myKey['id']]: myKey['value']}
                    output.update(newEntry)
    return output
```